# User name on top-right most tray vanished!

Tags: indicator, users, clock, username

User name on top-right most tray vanished!
I can't see it any more.
I see the power button and directly beside it is the clock, I'm using Ubuntu the latest version until now (v.12) 32-bit
Any solutions to get it back showing??

Answer (score 3):

Install `dconf-tools`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

From your dash unity search for dconf-tools

under apps-->indicator-session check user-show-menu as shown below in the pic

[image]

**Or you can use Ubuntu-tweak**

To install if you don't have yet:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

**Using Version 0.7.3**

Then go to **Tweaks** menu and choose **Session Indicator** and then under **User Indicator** you can Turn it Off

[image]